# LEFT JOIN 2 Table but will only return the 1st Record from Table2

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

table1

```
cid
itemdesc
itemprice
```

table2

```
cid
imagename
status
```

My 1st table is has unique cid (no duplicate) I want it to LEFT JOIN TO table2 but it has multiple rows per cid

```
cid      imagename           status
1        image1-of-cid1      test1
1        image2-of-cid1      test2
2        image1-of-cid2      test3
2        image2-of-cid2      test4
2        image3-of-cid2      test5
```

But I only want the Query to return the the 1st row only of the each record fom table 1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an extra subquery that gets one `imagename` per  `cid`. try this,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  cid, MIN(imagename) minImage
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY cid
        ) c ON a.cid = c.cid 
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON  c.cid = b.cid  AND
                b.imageName = c.minImage
```

- [***SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc3d4/1)

Comment: Any particular reason why to build such a complicated query and why it's better than the one I provided? (I'm really interested into your reasons, not just trolling)

Comment: @Vyktor because in your code, you have only included *non-aggregated* columns in your group by clause and no columns have been aggregate onb your select clause. this will give you invalid result. Please wait, I'll give you demo. Thanks for asking by the way.

Comment: Hmmm, mine solution [gives me the same result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15188/11/0) do you have any example/source that shows what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Vyktor well for this problem it works the same and this only specifically works on `MySQL`. but if this is in other RDBMS, you can't do that, try on this fiddle if it will still work [SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc439)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with John Woo's answer above. You need a subquery of some kind to actually retrieve the first row of table 2. Something like:

```
SELECT
t1.[id],
t2.*
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t2.cid = (SELECT TOP 1 cid FROM table2 WHERE cid = t1.cid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    distinct a.cid,a.itemdesc,b.imagename,a.itemprice,b.status
from table1 a,
table2 b
where a.cid=b.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.cid, a.itemdesc, a.itemprice, b.imagename, b.status 
FROM table1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.cid = b.cid 
GROUP BY a.cid, a.itemdesc, a.itemprice;
```